# Комментарии c++

Tags: c++, комментарии

В классе определена операция `/`. Пишу `x=a/*this`.

`/*` интепретируется как комментарий. Что делать?

Comment: Без подсветки синтаксиса было бы прикольнее)))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
x = a / *this;
```

или, в Вашем стиле:

```
x=a/ *this;
```

А можно ещё вот так:

```
x=a/(*this);
```

Comment: так дофига места занимает а отключить коменты можно?

Comment: @vityaaka47 Один пробел это дофига места?!! Это не отключается, ибо присутствует в стандарте языка.

Comment: ну лан спасиб))

Comment: @vityaaka47: почему у вас такая жесткая экономия памяти? Вы для нанороботов пишете программы?

Comment: @NickVolynkin у меня нанопрепод

Comment: @vityaaka47: ясно, сочувствую.

Comment: @vityaaka47 Во всех плюсовых стайлгайдах, что я видел, инфиксные операторы принято отделять пробелами от своих операндов. Как видно, это неспроста.

Comment: @D-side, неспроста - это когда в VS это единственный язык, в котором по умолчанию отключено автоматическое добавление пробелов вокруг операторов.

Comment: @Qwertiy странно, но в VS13 добавляет, специально не настраивал, правда установлен `Productivity Power Tools` в нагрузку.